# Grails 2.0 integration test pollution?

Tags: testing, grails, integration-testing, grails-2.0

So i have a small integration test that houses 5 tests in total. Running that test exclusively results in all tests passed. However running my entire test suite results in 4 test failures of the 5.

I've just recently upgraded to grails-2.0 from 1.3.7 and i switched from hsqldb to h2.

Has anyone any pointers in which direction i should be looking in order to fix this (test-pollution) problem?

**Domain model**

[image: domain-model]

**Integration test:**

```
class SeriesIntegrationTests extends GrailsUnitTestCase {
    Series series
    Episode episode

    protected void setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        series = new Series(ttdbId: 2348);
        episode = new Episode(ttdbId: 2983, season: 0, episodeNumber: 0, series: series);
    }

    protected void tearDown() {
        super.tearDown()
    }

    void testCreateSeries() {
        series.save()
        assertFalse("should not have validation errors : $series.errors", series.hasErrors())
        assertEquals("should be one series stored in db", 1, Series.count())
    }

    void testCreateEpisode() {
        series.save()
        episode.save()
        assertFalse("should not have validation errors : $episode.errors", episode.hasErrors())
        assertEquals("should be one episode stored in db", 1, Episode.count())
    }

    void testCreateSeriesAndAddEpisode() {
        series.addToEpisodes(episode)
        series.save(flush: true)
        series.refresh()
        assertEquals("series should contain one episode", 1, series.episodes.size())
    }

    void testDeleteSeriesAndCascadeToEpisode() {
        series.addToEpisodes(episode)
        series.save(flush: true)
        series.delete(flush: true)
        assertEquals(0, Episode.count())
        assertEquals(0, Series.count())

    }

    void testDeleteSeriesAndCascadeToBackdropImage() {
        series.backdrop = new Image();
        series.backdrop.binaryData = new byte[0]
        series.save(flush: true)

        assertFalse(series.hasErrors())
        assertEquals(1, Image.count())

        series.delete(flush: true)
        assertEquals(0, Image.count())
    }
}
```

Comment: you're a lot more likely to get help if you show the relevant code

Comment: Is the SeriesIntegrationTests under the /test/unit directory or the /test/integration directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution as to upgrade all the unit tests to grails 2.0 method of doing tests. When this was done, every test passed. So it seem's that unit tests somehow polluted integration tests. But only on certain hardware configurations.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when moving from 1.3.7 to 2.0. The integration tests were ok when launched with

```
grails test-app --integration
```

but were failing when launched with

```
grails test-app
```

I fixed everything by converting unit tests to grails 2.0 test (using annotations).

Comment: Still the same amount of failed tests with both commands. However, on my developer machine, everything is fine and dandy. no failed tests what so ever.. But on the CI server, it's failing these tests.

Comment: Are you recreating the database on CI every time the tests execute?  If not that could be causing the errors since you're assuming you don't have any previous objects in the DB.  Also, these tests don't look like they would be providing a whole lot of value since they are basically testing the behavior of Grails and not any code that you've written..

Comment: "create-drop" is specified in the config. So the database should be dropped on each run.