# Grails integration tests failing in a (seemingly) random and non-repeatable way

Tags: testing, grails, integration-testing, grails-plugin

We are writing integration tests for our Grails 2.0.0 application with the help of the [Fixtures](http://gpc.github.com/grails-fixtures/docs/index.html) and [Buid-Test-Data](https://bitbucket.org/tednaleid/grails-test-data/wiki/Home) plugins.

During testing, it was discovered that the integration test fail at certain times, and pass at other times. Running 'test-app' sometimes results in all tests passing, and sometimes results in some of our tests failing.

When the tests fail, they are caused by a unique constraint being violated during the insert of an instance of a domain class. This would indicate that there are still records in the test DB. I am running the H2 db, and have definitely got 'dbCreate = "create-drop"' in my DataSource.groovy.

[Grails 2.0 integration test pollution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8985152/grails-2-0-integration-test-pollution) seems to indicate there is a significant test-pollution problem in Grails. Are there any solutions to this? Have I hit [Grails-8530](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8530)?

[Edit] the test-pollution seems to be caused by the unit tests. We have sort-of proved this by deleting the unit tests and successfully running 'test-app' repeatedly.

Answer (score 5):

When I run into errors like this I like to try and find the unit test(s) that is causing the problem.  This might be kinda tricky since yours seem to only be failing on occasion.

1) I'd look at unit tests that were recently added.  If this problem just started happening then that's a good place to look.

2) Metaclassing seems to be good at causing these type of errors so I'd look for metaclassing that isn't setup/torn down properly.  Not as much of an issue with 2.0 as with <= 1.3.7 but could be the problem.

3) I wrote a plugin that executes your tests in a random order.  Which might not help you solve your current problem.  But what might help you is it prints out all of your tests so you can take what it gives you and run `grails test-app <pasted list of unit tests> IntegrationTestThatIsFailing` then start removing unit tests to find the culprit(s). ( http://grails.org/plugin/random-test-order).  I found a bug in this with 2.0 that I haven't had time to fix yet (integration tests fail when asserting on rendered view name) but it should still print out your test names for you (which is better than doing it yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

The fact integration tests fail with a constraint violation due to existing records reminds me of a situation I once encountered with functional tests (selenium) executing in unpredictable order, some of them not cleaning up the database properly. Sure, the situation with functional tests is different, since it is more difficult to restore the database state (The testcase cannot rollback a transaction in another jvm).

Although integration tests usually roll back transactions, it is still possible to break this behavior if your code controls transactions (commits) explicitly.

First, I would try forcing execution order as mentioned by Jarred in 3). Assuming you can then reproduce the behavior, I would then check transactional behaviour next. Setting the logging level of `org.hibernate.transaction` to debug should show you where transaction boundaries are.

Sorry, don't yet have a good explanation why wiping out the unit tests helps getting rid of the symptoms besides a general "possibly metaclassing issues". :)